# SQL FOR XML multilevel from one pivoted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, for-xml

I've been trying to use FOR XML without success to do the following.

Source table:

```
Country            | ID      | 1950        | 1955
-----------------------------------------------------
Country 1          | 1       | 2.43        | 2.55
Country 2          | 2       | 4.54        | 42.15
```

Desired output:

```
<locations>
  <location>
    <loc name='Country 1' id='1' />
    <dub>
      <data year='1950' value='2.43' />
      <data year='1955' value='2.55' />
    </dub>
  </location>
  <location>
    <loc name='Country 2' id='2' />
    <dub>
      <data year='1950' value='4.54' />
      <data year='1955' value='42.15' />
    </dub>
  </location>
</locations>
```

Will it be necessary to unpivot for the dub element? I wanted the simplest SQL query possible.
I think FOR XML is too difficult to use. You should be able to specify the hierarchy just using simple XPath on column names but it won't accept, for example, `[dub/data/@year=1955/@value]` as the name of the column `[1950]`.

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: Several, like: `SELECT locname as [@name], locid as [@id], [1950] as [v1950],[1955] as [v1955]
FROM ##test t
FOR XML PATH('location'), ROOT('locations')`. The problem is related to the `dub` element, can't make it. Tried with subquery but no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d610b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table YourTable
(
  Country varchar(20),
  ID int,
  [1950] numeric(5,2),
  [1955] numeric(5,2)
)

insert into YourTable values
('Country 1',           1,        2.43,         2.55),
('Country 2',           2,        4.54,         42.15)
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select T.Country as 'loc/@name',
       T.ID as 'loc/@id',
       (
         select 1950 as 'data/@year',
                T.[1950] as 'data/@value',
                null,
                1955 as 'data/@year',
                T.[1955] as 'data/@value'
         for xml path(''), type
       ) as dub
from YourTable as T
for xml path('location'), root('locations'), type
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d610b/1/0)**:

```xml
<locations>
  <location>
    <loc name="Country 1" id="1" />
    <dub>
      <data year="1950" value="2.43" />
      <data year="1955" value="2.55" />
    </dub>
  </location>
  <location>
    <loc name="Country 2" id="2" />
    <dub>
      <data year="1950" value="4.54" />
      <data year="1955" value="42.15" />
    </dub>
  </location>
</locations>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The trick was the `null` column you added - it made a break of the elements. Could you just clarify why it happens this way? It's not intuitive that a `null` column would break into a separate element!

Comment: @igorjrr Replace the null with a value and a column alias and you will have a node and a a value in between. Remove the column alias and you end up with a value between the nodes. Finally remove the value and you have something that separates the nodes without ending up in the XML. The result should be the same if you use an empty string '' instead of null.