# SQL FOR XML multilevel from one pivoted table - grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, for-xml

This is going further from the question posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250367/sql-for-xml-multilevel-from-one-pivoted-table). The solution proposed worked well, but now I have a harder scenario and the same solution is not applying since SQL is not allowing to create a third nested `SELECT`.
The scenario now is that the `dub` tag can be repeated inside each `location` and each `dub` may contain several `data` tags.
An example:

```
<locations>
  <location>
    <loc name="Country 1" id="1" />
    <dubs>
      <dub name="City 1">
        <data year="1950" value="2.43" />
        <data year="1955" value="2.55" />
      </dub>
      <dub name="City 2">
        <data year="1950" value="5.67" />
        <data year="1955" value="4.42" />
      </dub>
    </dubs>
  </location>
  <location>
    <loc name="Country 2" id="2" />
    <dubs>
      <dub bane="City ABC">
        <data year="1950" value="4.54" />
        <data year="1955" value="42.15" />
      </dub>
    </dubs>
  </location>
</locations>
```

I've tried to do a third nested `SELECT` but it is not allowed:
[SQL Fiddle - Not Working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab396/3)

```
select T.Country as 'loc/@name',
       T.ID as 'loc/@id',
       (
         select [City] as 'dub/@name',
         (
           select 1950 as 'dub/data/@year',
                  T.[1950] as 'dub/data/@value',
                  null,
                  1955 as 'dub/data/@year',
                  T.[1955] as 'dub/data/@value'
           for xml path(''), type
          ) as dub
       ) as dubs
from YourTable as T
for xml path('location'), root('locations'), type
```

I've modified the solution for the original question and produced the following query, which almost works:
[SQL Fiddle - Almost Working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab396/5)

```
    select T.Country as 'loc/@name',
       T.ID as 'loc/@id',
       (
         select [City] as 'dub/@name',
                 1950 as 'dub/data/@year',
                  T.[1950] as 'dub/data/@value',
                  null,
                  1955 as 'dub/data/@year',
                  T.[1955] as 'dub/data/@value'
           for xml path(''), type
       ) as dubs
from YourTable as T
for xml path('location'), root('locations'), type
```

However, you'll see that the `data` tag is not being grouped inside it's `dub` tag - the `dub` tag is being recreated with a blank `name` attribute content.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Gasper, you were very helpful! (Gasper is my imaginary friend)

I found the solution, below:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/556bc/1)

```
select Country as 'loc/@name',
       ID as 'loc/@id',
       (
         select [City] as 'dub/@name',
           (
               select 1950 as 'data/@year',
                  [1950] as 'data/@value',
                  null,
                  1955 as 'data/@year',
                  [1955] as 'data/@value'
               from YourTable as D
               where Country = C.Country
               and City = T.City
               for xml path(''), type
             ) as 'dub/datavalues'
         from
         (
           select distinct City
           from YourTable
           where Country = C.Country
         ) as T
         for xml path(''), type
       ) as 'loc/dubs'
from
(
  select distinct Country, ID
  from YourTable
) as C
for xml path(''), root('locations'), type
```

:)